# Find highest spot with Google Earth API?

Tags: vb6, gis, google-earth-plugin

I needed to find out the highest point of a region.

However when I iterate through all the points isn't efficient enough for a my CPU.

So does Google Earth API provide any relevant approach ?

Thanks !

Comment: What does this have to do with App Engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not see Google Earth API provides anything about this, but you may add elevation as a parameter to reduce results, and give it an increment until the result's count is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Since this point doesn't change often, I would just use a constant.

```
'Mount Everest (WGS84)
highest_lat = 27.988056
highest_lon = 86.925278
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code it is impossible to say where the overhead is. However, in general, you should pass your multiple calls to the api using the google.earth.executeBatch method.

https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/google_earth_namespace#ab26414915202d39cad12bcd5bd99e739

This method efficiently executes an arbitrary, user-defined function minimizing the amount of overhead incurred during cross-process communication between the web browser and Google Earth Plugin.

Here is a working example

http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/batch.html